# CSS border-image linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

I tried (and succeeded) in creating a design using `border-image` and `linear-gradient`. My issue is I'm not exactly sure what I did. The syntax is confusing me. I understand that the series of colors is the way it fades from color to color and that the first value denotes direction, but the `1 25%` at the end is a complete mystery. I played around with those values and `to bottom right` a lot, but couldn't quite figure out how they relate to each other. Can somebody explain what each value means?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to get the same effect with `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, and `-o-` versions. Bonus bonus points if you can explain those syntaxes as well.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, white, black, white, black) 1 25%;
  
 /*   -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, from(black), to(white)) 1 100%;
     -webkit-border-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white, black, white, black) 1 100%;
     -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(black, white) 1 100%;
     -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(black, white) 1 100%; */

}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you still not clear !

Answer (score 0):

`linear gradient` is creates an `<image>` which represents a linear gradient of colors.

Here the explaination for `linear gradient`.

```
linear-gradient( 
  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+ )
  \---------------------------------/ \----------------------------/
    Definition of the gradient line        List of color stops  

where <side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
  and <color-stop>     = <color> [ <percentage> | <length> ]?
```

**Browser specific with default one.**

```
-webkit-gradient(<type>, <point> [, <radius>]?, <point> [, <radius>]? [, <stop>]*) // Safari / Chrome
-moz-linear-gradient([ [ [top | bottom] || [left | right] ],]? <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+); // Firefox
linear-gradient( [ [ <angle> | [top | bottom] || [left | right] ],]? <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+); // Normal
```

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/linear-gradients/

Answer (score -1):

I think is something like this.

```
border-image-slice: 1 25%
```

here is the documentation [MDN Border image and attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)